# Como instanciar una Variable de plantilla en C++

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de instanciar explícitamente una especialización de plantilla pero es para variables. Todo funcionaba bien cuando tenia el código completo en el `main.cpp`, pero los problemas vinieron cuando tuve que mover todo a su respectivo `header file` y `cpp file` y recibo  un error de compilación:

Código completo que si funciona al estar todo el contenido en el main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>


//declaracion de la plantilla de variable
template <int T>
double mvar;

//instanciacion explicita
template<>
double mvar<0> = 3.1415;

int main(){

    //uso de la variable
    std::cout << mvar<0> << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

salida:

```
3.1415
```

Este es el código cuando los separo en main.cpp, mateC.cpp y mateC.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MateC.hpp"


int main(){

    //uso de la variable
    std::cout << matec::mvar<0> << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

luego tengo el header mateC.hpp

```
#ifndef MATEC_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MATEC_HPP_INCLUDED


namespace matec{

    //declaracion de la plantilla de variable
    template <int T>
    double mvar;

}



#endif // MATEC_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Y por ultimo el mateC.cpp

```
#include "MateC.hpp"


namespace matec{

    //instanciacion explicita
    template<>
    double mvar<0> = 3.1415;

}
```

Entonces recibo un Error de compilación:

```
c:/program files/mingw_x64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj\Release\MateC.o:MateC.cpp:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `matec::mvar<0>'; obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.data$_ZN5matec4mvarILi0EEE[_ZN5matec4mvarILi0EEE]+0x0): first defined here
```

Estoy compilando en windows 10 usando CodeBlocks versión 20.03 y el compilador es MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders 11.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Las plantillas no se pueden separar en archivos de cabecera (`hpp`) y código (`cpp`), las plantillas sólo pueden estar presentes en archivos de cabecera. Esto es <strike>una característica</strike> un problema conocido de las plantillas de C++, ya lo está avisando el compilador:

> ```
> multiple definition of `matec::mvar<0>'
> ```

Nos indica que `matec::mvar<0>` ha sido definida múltiples veces ¿cuándo? Una de las veces en `main`:

```
std::cout << matec::mvar<0> << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Se instancia mvar<0>, lo que provoca su definición.
```

Y la otra en el archivo de código:

```
namespace matec{

    //instanciacion explicita
    template<>
    double mvar<0> = 3.1415;
//         ^^^^^^^ <--- Se instancia mvar<0>, lo que provoca su definición.
}
```

No voy a entrar en detalles de por qué funciona así (si quieres saberlo, te animo a redactar una pregunta sobre ese tema concreto), tendrás que hacer la especialización en la cabecera.

Answer (score 1):

Las plantillas no funcionan igual que las clases normales. Cuando tu declaras una plantilla, el compilador se la guarda y no hace nada más con ella, no genera código ni nada parecido. Se espera a encontrar usos de dicha plantilla para empezar a generar código. Esto quiere decir que para generar código debe conocer previamente qué código debe generar.

Por otro lado tenemos que el compilador de C++ no tiene un conocimiento de *proyecto* sino que maneja unidades de compilación. Una unidad de compilación no es más que un archivo cpp junto con todos los includes (directos o indirectos) que contiene.

Toda esta parrafada sirve para que entiendas el error. Te copio el main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MateC.hpp"

int main(){

    //uso de la variable
    std::cout << matec::mvar<0> << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas, estás incluyendo `MateC.hpp`, pero ahí no se encuentra la especialización `mvar<0>`, pues dicha especialización se encuentra en `MateC.cpp`. Lo que está sucediendo entonces es que `main.o` tendrá una implementación de `mvar<0>` basada en la plantilla básica, es decir, sin valor definido, mientras que `MateC.cpp` estará declarando una versión de `mvar<0>` distinta.

Al enlazar ambos archivos, el enlazador ve que las dos implementaciones son distintas y genera el error.

¿Cómo te proteges ante esto?

Lo más sencillo sería dejar la declaración de la plantilla y la especialización en el mismo archivo.

Otra opción sería declarar `mvar` como expresión constante. Actualmente `mvar` está declarada como una variable, lo cual te permite modificar su valor en cualquier momento. Al declarar la variable como expresión constante consigues invalidar la plantilla base:

```
template <int T>
constexpr double mvar;
```

Si tu ahora intentas usar `mvar<0>`, y no has hecho un include a dicha especialización, el programa directamente no compilará. Las expresiones constantes necesitan un valor.

Vale, ahora tampoco te compila. La diferencia está en que ahora el error que se genera te indica que estás intentando usar `constexpr double mvar;`, que se corresponde con la plantilla base.

La especialización, ya puestos, también debería ser `constexpr`:

```
template<>
constexpr double mvar<0> = 3.14;
```